# Записать число в обратном порядке (69=>96)

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

Задача состоит в том, чтобы записать число в обратном порядке (например, 69 => 96).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Perevorot: array [1..100] of integer;
  MyIndex, MySum: integer;
begin
  MySum := StrToInt(Edit1.Text); // На входе 69

  for MyIndex := 10 to 1 do
    MySum := MySum - Perevorot[MyIndex];

  Edit2.Text := IntToStr(MySum); // <<-- Тут должно быть 96
end;
```

У меня получается, результат по прежнему 69. Подскажите, в чём ошибка?

Comment: @Kromster, а что тут еще можно улучшить? :-)

Comment: @Kromster, ну картинка типа показывает, что не переворачивает. Можешь править больше не буду срывать :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А не проще ли преобразовывать в число, а потом переписать строку в обратном порядке (найти длину и, начиная с конца, записать в переменную в цикле)?

Answer (score 2):

Я не смог понять логики программы, но вижу, что неверно указан оператор цикла. Надо downto вместо to. Сейчас цикл for не работает.

Comment: @Get спасибо, цикл действительно не работал. Но ожидаемого результата я все равно не получил. Буду переделывать программу.

Comment: Вам же уже советовали использовать обратную запись строки, стандартную процедуру Delphi или целочисленное деление на 10. Вы пытаетесь изобрести велосипед?

Comment: Если надо делать через массив, то можно каждую цифру числа записать в массив, а потом вывести все элементы массива в обратном порядке.